# Prove that two linear map are same --- from “A invitation to 3-d vision"

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product, computer-vision

I found a question from the book to prove the following equation:
$A^T\hat{\omega}A=\widehat{A^{-1}\omega}$.

where $\hat{}$ means turn a vector $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ into a skew-symmetric matrix
$
  \left[\begin{matrix}
   0 & -x_3 & x_2 \\
   x_3 & 0 & -x_1 \\
   -x_2 & x_1 & 0
  \end{matrix}\right]
$
and A is a rotation matrix. How to prove it? One hint the book gives is, prove two linear maps, $A^T\hat{(.)}A$ and $\widehat{A^{-1}(.)}$ are the same.
Thank you for reading the question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\widehat{x}$ is the **cross product matrix** such that $\widehat{x}y=x\times y$ for every vector $y$. Therefore, the problem boils down to proving that
$$
u\cdot\left(A^T(\omega\times Av)\right)=u\cdot\left((A^{-1}\omega)\times v\right)
$$
for every pair of vectors $u$ and $v$. The [scalar triple product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product) should be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer of "user1551". From his help I come up with a way.
But I don't use the [scalar triple product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product)(may be I haven't totally understand his proof). My proof is:

for the equation $A^T\hat{\omega}A=\widehat{A^{-1}\omega}$, multiply vector u on both right, we need to prove:
$$ A^T(\omega \times(Au)) = (A^{-1}\omega)\times u$$ 
Since $A^T$ is a rotate matrix, and it preserve the angle between vectors, we got
$$ A^T(\omega \times(Au)) = (A^T\omega) \times (A^TAu) = (A^{-1}\omega)\times u  $$
So it is proved.

Comment: The official explanation is that "A rigid body motion or a special Eucildean transformation preserves the cross product of any two vectors."

Comment: Your last step is incorrect. In general, $A^T(x\times y)\ne(A^Tx)\times(A^Ty)$. Therefore the equality $A^T(\omega\times(Au))=(A^T\omega)\times(A^TAu)$ is not justified. Also, the question only says that $\det(A)=1$, not that $A$ is real orthogonal. So, you don't have $A^TA=I$ and the equality $(A^T\omega)\times(A^TAu)=(A^{-1}\omega)\times u$ is again unjustified.

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstood the meaning of the question of the book, and it says A is a rotation matrix, which means it is orthogonal.I will edit the question later.